# Как мне сделать чтобы при вводе команды без enter сразу водилась как нажал на 1 или 2 пункт?

Tags: python

Код скрипта:

```
from colorama import init, Fore #/
from colorama import Back       #|
from colorama import Style      #|
#-----------Библы-----------------

print("")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
print(" ")
print("Выберите:")
print("1: Старт игры")
print("2: Выбор версии")
print("3: Настройка лаунчера")
all_text = []
while True:
    val = input("Ввод текста>>> ")
    if val=="":
        break
    else:
        all_text.append(val)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы реализовать возможность выбора опции без необходимости нажимать `Enter`, вам понадобится использовать модуль `msvcrt` для `Windows`

```
def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

while True:
    key = get_char()
    if key == "1":
        option = "Старт игры"
        print(option)
    elif key == "2":
        option = "Выбор версии"
        print(option)
    elif key == "3":
        option = "Настройка лаунчера"
        print(option)
    elif key == "q":
        break
```

Comment: Консоль крашит, ошибка какая -то, не могу понять, может быть я плохо вставил
```
import msvcrt                   #|
#-----------Библы-----------------

def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

 while True:
     key = get_char()
     if key == "1":
         option = "Старт игры"
         break
     elif key == "2":
         option = "Выбор версии"
         break
     elif key == "3":
         option = "Настройка лаунчера"
         break
     elif key == "q":
         break
```
(Не смог ставить всё из-за ограничений)

Comment: @vu4eke Какая ошибка?

Comment: А я не знаю, консоль крашит, как мне оставить консоль чтобы она не закрывалась сразу?

Comment: @Vu4eke Исправил, проверьте

Comment: консоль не крашит но при выборе пункта он крашит, как мне сделать чтобы при нажатие на 2 или 3 очистилась консоль и снова написалась та же что при первом но с некоторыеми изменениям?

Comment: @Vu4eke Вы используете ОС Windows?

Comment: да, у меня windows

Comment: @Vu4eke Тогда какая ошибка ?

Comment: А ошибки нету, после вода 1 например консоль просто закрывается без ошибки (выводится сообщение и за милисикунду закрыывается)

Comment: @Vu4eke удалите все `break`, кроме пункта `q` и вывод переменной `print(option)` поставьте внутри цикла

Comment: Когда я нажимаю 3 например нечего не происходит, не водится не крашит и нечего не выводит(

Comment: Все работает) скопируйте еще раз мой код, выход на q

Comment: а, точно, работает, а как мне задать что делает 2 или 3 пункт? Например я нажимаю на 3 и мне выводит еще другие пункты, но при этом чтобы она дублировалось как новый консоль (чтобы выполнялась команда clear и новые сообщение)

Comment: @Vu4eke `If else` в помощь

Comment: А можешь дать примерный код? Я просто новичок

Comment: @Vu4eke Впрочем, это уже другая история)

Comment: Верно, это уже мои хотелки пошли, извини XD

Comment: @Vu4eke Если Ваш вопрос готов, тогда нажмите на галку возле ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Вот фулл код которые я поставил:

```
from colorama import init, Fore #/
from colorama import Back       #|
from colorama import Style      #|
import msvcrt                   #|
#-----------Библы-----------------

print("")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ███████╗██╗░░░░░░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░")
print(Fore.WHITE + "      ██╔════╝██║░░░░░██╔══██╗██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      █████╗░░██║░░░░░███████║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░╚═╝███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝")
print(Fore.BLUE + "      ██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██╔══██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░██╗██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗")
print(Fore.RED + "      ███████╗███████╗██║░░██║╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║")
print(Fore.RED + "      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝")
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print("                От создателей EscapeWorld〡Выбран сервер: SCreate")
print(" ")
print("Выберите:")
print("1: Старт игры")
print("2: Выбор версии")
print("3: Настройка лаунчера")

def get_char():
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')

option = ""

 while True:
     key = get_char()
     if key == "1":
         option = "Старт игры"
         break
     elif key == "2":
         option = "Выбор версии"
         break
     elif key == "3":
         option = "Настройка лаунчера"
         break
     elif key == "q":
         break
```